# Class not found issue (Composer, PHPUnit)

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

Getting the following error form PHPUnit:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FoobarTest\Money\Money'
not found in /www/foobar/tests/FoobarTest/Money/MoneyTest.php on line 11
```

My structure is like:

```
/src/Foobar/Money/Money.php (class Money, namespace Foobar\Money)

/tests/FoobarTest/Money/Money.php (class Money, namespace FoobarTest\Money)
```

Autoloading done through composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Foobar\\": "src/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "FoobarTest\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Tried with PSR0, PSR2, PSR4, ...

MoneyTest class:

```
<?php
namespace FoobarTest\Money;


class MoneyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // ...
```

Money class:

```
<?php
namespace Foobar\Money;


class Money
{
    // ...
```

**Why is it trying to load** `FoobarTest\Money\Money` instead of `Foobar\Money\Money` ?

Comment: So how do you use `Money` class in your test? I don't see you've imported it with `use` at all.

Comment: lulz *aaaah* ... that was the hint I been looking for @zerkms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help php autoloader (and composer) you must import the target class using

```
use Foobar\Money\Money;
```

in your test file.

Also you probably want to give your test file a `MoneyTest.php` name to match the corresponding class name.

Comment: I was using `Foobar\Money\Money` inside `FoobarTest\...` without declaring the full qualified class reference.

Comment: "*OK (1 test, 1 assertion)*" :-)))